# Do I have to mark a MySQL varchar Column as binary when using utf8_bin collation?

Tags: mysql, binary, collation

I have a table a MySQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `urlpt` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Case sensitivity matters.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `urlpt_UNIQUE` (`urlpt`),
  KEY `urlpt_INDEX` (`urlpt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I was wondering if I have to set the column `urlpt` as binary, because I do use `utf8_bin` collation. (I want to handle e.g. a and á and â and so on as different characters...)

Comment: Are you having a problem?  If so, could you describe the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to.  If the data really is UTF-8, then storing it as a UTF-8 VARCHAR as you've done is fine.

And you use the collation to tell MySQL how things should be sorted/compared - as you've done.

Have you actually had a problem?

Comment: Sequel Pro turned the column `urlpt` each time to binary, that's why I was wondering, if I missed something. I was afraid of running into trouble later on, so I decided to ask and get it right from the start. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

No; in fact you should rather set it to 'utf8_general_ci'.

The difference is that utf8_bin is case-sensitive and 'A' is sometheing else than 'a', that means if you ever do a query `'... WHERE urlpt LIKE "F%B%"'` then it will only return 'FooBar', but not 'foobar'.

Comment: This seems to be making an assumption about the OP's needs.  I assumed that if he was using utf8_bin it meant he wanted it that way.  Worth pointing out though, to others who may not know what utf8_bin is.